# ReadDirectoryChangesW does not capture FILE_ACTION_ADDED when copying or creating files

Tags: c++, c, windows, file-monitoring

I'm trying to use `ReadDirectoryChangesW` to track when a file is created, copied or moved to a monitored directory.

My problem is that when I copy or create a file on the monitored directory there is no FILE_ACTION_ADDED event captured by `ReadDirectoryChangesW`, only FILE_ACTION_MODIFIED events are captured instead.

On the other hand, when I move a file (instead of copying or creating) from another directory to the monitored directory then a FILE_ACTION_ADDED is captured.

I was wondering if someone know a way to make ReadDirectoryChangesW capture FILE_ACTION_ADDED on my 3 cases: create, copy and move.

I call `ReadDirectoryChangesW` like this:

```
ReadDirectoryChangesW(directory_handle, buffer, MAX_EVENTs_BUFFER,
    FALSE, FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME | FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME |
    FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE | FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE,
    NULL, (LPOVERLAPPED)usr_data, FileIOCompletionRoutine)
```

And I use `CreateFileA` to initialize the `directory_handle`:

```
CreateFileA(directory_path.c_str(), 
    FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE |
    FILE_SHARE_DELETE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS | 
    FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL);
```

Then, on my `FileIOCompletionRoutine` I never receive an FILE_ACTION_ADDED when I copy a file to the monitored directory, or when I create a file, only when I move a file. Is this the normal behaviour or am I doing something wrong?

Edit 1:

```
VOID CALLBACK FileIOCompletionRoutine(_In_ DWORD err, _In_ DWORD bytes, _Inout_ LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped)
{
    CUSTOM_OVERLAPPED* pCustomOverlapped = (CUSTOM_OVERLAPPED*)lpOverlapped;
    char* buffer_offset = (char*)pCustomOverlapped->buffer;
    PFILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION pInfo = (PFILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION)buffer_offset;

    do
    {        
        pInfo = (PFILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION)buffer_offset;
        switch (pInfo->Action)
        {
            case FILE_ACTION_ADDED:
            {              
                std::cout << "file added!\n";
                break;
            }
            case FILE_ACTION_MODIFIED:
            {
                std::cout << "file modified!\n";
                break;
            }
            // and so on...
        }
        buffer_offset += pInfo->NextEntryOffset;        
    } while(pInfo->NextEntryOffset);
}
```

Edit 2:

I found out that if I remove the `FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE` from the `ReadDirectoryChangesW` the `FILE_ACTION_ADDED` event is captured correctly when I create new files and when I do a cut and paste, but not if I do a copy and paste in which case it fires a `FILE_ACTION_MODIFIED`. In order to get a `FILE_ACTION_ADDED` when I do a copy and paste into the monitored directory I need to remove the `FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE` flag too.

So, this way if a want to track new files (created, copied or moved) inside the monitored directory I only need the flags `FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME | FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME` on the `ReadDirectoryChangesW` function.
If I want to track modified (already present in the directory) files I need `FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE`, but I can not use an or of the three flags on the `ReadDirectoryChangesW` to track new files and modified files.

Has any of you found a way to track all this events with an logical or of the three flags or do I have to call `ReadDirectoryChangesW` with different flags for each case?

Answer (score 1):

In fact `ReadDirectoryChangesW` returns a buffer that can contain more than one `FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION` structure. The first one is as expected at the beginning of the buffer, but if the field `NextEntryOffset` is not null, it is the offset (in the char buffer) for the next structure.

So your callback should be:

```
VOID CALLBACK FileIOCompletionRoutine(_In_ DWORD err, _In_ DWORD bytes, _Inout_ LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped)
{
    CUSTOM_OVERLAPPED* pCustomOverlapped = (CUSTOM_OVERLAPPED*)lpOverlapped;
    char* buffer_offset = (char*)pCustomOverlapped->buffer;
    PFILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION pInfo = (PFILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION)buffer_offset;

    do {
        switch (pInfo->Action)
        {
            case FILE_ACTION_ADDED:
            {              
                std::cout << "file added!\n";
                break;
            }
            case FILE_ACTION_MODIFIED:
            {
                std::cout << "file modified!\n";
                break;
            }
            // and so on...
        }
        pInfo = (PFILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION)(buffer_offset + pInfo->NextEntryOffset);
    } while (0 != pInfo->NextEntryOffset);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Serge I was already doing that while loop, I did not copy the snippet correctly, sorry. I have just edited the question.

The thing is that when I create a new file on the monitored directory I get 2 FILE_ACTION_MODIFIED events, but none of FILE_ACTION_ADDED. The same occurs when I copied a file.